# How would you refer to a Warlord?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If Jack was a Lord, or a King, or a Knight, he would be called Lord Jack, King Jack or Sir Jack, respectively.

So let's say Jack is a Warlord, would you call him "Warlord Jack"? or just Lord? or just Jack?

Answer (score 4):

He's a ***warlord***. That's the kind of person who's used to getting his way. If you know what's good for you, you'll call him whatever he wants!

That said, "[warlord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlord)" is not a standard title of nobility in any system I know of. The word suggests that he's a military commander who has used his military power to take a position of government authority, so he can rule. It kind of has a negative connotation that way: he is someone who has seized power by violence (most societies don't usually consider that a legitimate claim to rule). Usually, someone in that position will probably give himself some other, more socially acceptable, title.

Answer (score 0):

"Warlord" is a position or role, not an honorific. "Warlord Bob" is like calling someone "Bowling Instructor Fred" or "Nail Manicurist Maxine". It's not necessarily *incorrect*, but it isn't how a native speaker would formulate the sentence.

To speak ABOUT Bob the Warlord, one would phrase it thusly: "Bob the Warlord."

To speak TO Bob to Warlord, one would address him however he bloody well likes to be styled. "Lord Bob", or "sir", or "please-don't-kill-me-I-have-a-wife-and-three-kids" would all be syntactically-valid.